# Why not the Orthodox beliefs instead of splitting away?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, church-history, reformation

Why not the Orthodox beliefs instead of the Protestant Reformation? What prompted the Reformers to "rewrite" everything?

Comment: Your question Has a multitude of answers, I think that you might clear up some of your questions by studying Church History. John Calvin who began the Protestant movement had very good reasons for breaking away from the Church of Rome. Many others left for varying reasons.

Comment: Pardon my error I meant to say Martin Luther and not John Calvin.

Comment: This question has the same issues as the other one. Please clarify what you mean and define the terms you are using. You seem to imply that the Reformers came up with something new that was nothing like the Christianity of centuries past; many Protestants would disagree. After all, everyone thinks that what they believe is what Jesus believed, therefore, they are "orthodox" and everyone else is not.

Comment: Don't know what you guys are complaining about this is an awesome question

Comment: Ooopsy...misinterpreted the question :)

Comment: long story short...by the 16th cent., the reformers' DNA was so engrained with western theology that consideration of eastern theology never had chance. The reformers were the great grandchildren of the scholastic movement..which pretty much nailed the lid on the coffin for east west unity. The 2 big ones - the filioque and original sin were simply taken for granted in the western middle ages. What little familiarity that protestants had of eastern thought was simply dismissed as heterdoxy.

Comment: Unfortunately this still exists in Western christianity today...especially here in the Bible belt. The majority of people I know personally turn to the film *My Big Fat Greek Wedding* as their only knowledge source of *anything* Greek. By the time John Calvin was born into protestantism the only practical things that protestants had in common with the East were anti papal sentiment and faith in Jesus